# Mac OSX connected to an Active Directory domain is not mapping to the network drive over VPN. I suspect DNS, but the settings all look fine

Tags: macos, vpn, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, hamachi

I've got a remote user that's using a new MAC book pro to log into the windows domain via LogMeIn Hamachi. Hamachi is connecting to the domain:

[image]

I can ping the mac book from the Hamachi Server it's connected to by ip. I can ping from the Macbook to the file server using dns...

ping fileserver

I get a response, but the ip address is incorrect. It should be 192.168.1.13. However, it's reporting back as something like: 10.0.10.40.

I have bound the MacBook to the doamin as here:
[image]

I have configured the Primary domain server to be the main Domain controller through Directory Utility:

[image]

I have DNS configured in the domain for fileserver to be 192.168.1.13, the server has a static IP.

I had this laptop connected to the network drives, before I sent it and everything worked fine from a remote test site.

I'm looking to find out where the problem with DNS has occurred.

I have followed all step [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/integrate-macs-into-a-windows-active-directory-domain/) & [here](http://blog.pluralsight.com/join-mac-to-windows-domain).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where does the 10.0.10.40 address come from? what do you get when you do a ```dig fileserver``` on the mac? Do you get more than one address as reply?

Comment: @heiglandreas I'm almost positive that the 10.0.10.40 is coming from Hamachi (VPN client). I haven't tried the dig command from the Mac but I will, and I'll post the results.

Comment: Hamachi is said to explicitly NOT use the 10.x.y.z range (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29#Addressing)

Comment: @heiglandreas It say that it excludes the 10.x.y.z range on the client side. The 10.x.y.z address is coming from the server side, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible culprits, that I could think of, for this situation were:

•   VPN tunnel failing or VPN misconstruing DNS

•   MacBook not being joined to the domain

•   User account permissions not being configured properly

•   Client or server side firewall configuration inaccuracy

•   Local Network ID and Remote User's Network ID matching, causing conflict

I tested the first four items extensively and found no errors. The fifth scenario was the only possibility. I sent the remote user to another network to test the matching netID theory. All drives mapped successfully.

In this situation the issue was matching NetIDs of the local network and the remote network.